# How can I sequentially take elements from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

My question seems to you to be easy and stupid, but I was able to solve it myself.

I have array **x**:

```
let x = [
    {"ID":"123456"},
    {"ID":"789456"},
    {"ID":"303099"},
    {"ID":"300446"},
    {"ID":"300234"}
];
```

And There is the variable **y** that randomly takes elements from an array:

```
let y = x[Math.floor(Math.random() * x.length)];
```

Then I use **y** in another function.

Now I need to sequentially take the elements from the array (first x[0], x[1] , etc.) and pass them to another function.

That is, i need a similar variable like **y**, which will pass the array elements sequentially.

How can this be implemented? through the counter?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What you are saying sounds like a for loop. If that is not what you want, anyway you will need to keep track of the index you are at. Use one index variable and refer to the array elements like this x[index]

Answer (score 0):

Create a copy and use [`Array.shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) to extract the elements from that in a loop:

```js
let x =
[
  {"ID":"123456"},
  {"ID":"789456"},
  {"ID":"303099"},
  {"ID":"300446"},
  {"ID":"300234"}
];
// create a copy
let copy = [...x];

// loop it
while(copy.length) {
  const x = copy.shift();
  doSomethingWithX(x);
  console.log(`[copy] now ${JSON.stringify(copy)}`);
}

function doSomethingWithX(x) {
  console.log(`Here's [x.ID] for you ${x.ID}`)
}
```

Comment: @Kooilnc, how could I access const x outside of the loop?

Comment: See edited answer for a possibility (pass x to some external function)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (const el of x) {
  yourFunction(el);
}
```